# go-pg: Push data to existing array

Tags: sql, postgresql, go, orm, go-pg

I want to add a new value to a string array in postgres db using go-pg. How could I push a new value to the array using go-pg.

This is my user model

```
type User struct {
    ID        string    `pg:"id,notnull,unique" json:"id"`
    Email     string    `pg:"email,notnull,unique" json:"email"`
    Skills    []string  `pg:"skills,array" json:"skill"`
}
```

I want to update the skills array whenever user adds a new skill using the userid.

Data from client contains the userid and a single skill selected by the user.

In `go-pg` we can update a column in the following way

```
pg.Model(user).Set("data = ?data").Where("id = ?id").Update()
```

But how could I push a new data to the array?

Comment: Please provide sample data and desired results.

Comment: you mean append an element to an array? in pg there is a function `array_append`. check it out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Yun Luo suggested I have done with `array_append`.

```
pg.Exec(`UPDATE users SET skills = array_append(skills, 'skill') WHERE id = 'id';`)
```